# `this` binding and call-site of `this`

Tags: javascript, object, binding, this

Does a function have access to all info in its call site?

I thought that maybe a function would have access to its call sites scope otherwise I may be mistaken so I'd appreciate feedback and an explanation.

```
function bar() {
    // call-stack is: `bar`
    // so, our call-site is in the global scope
    let a = “heyo”;
    console.log( “bar” );
    foo(); // ← call-site for `foo`
}

function foo() {
    // call-stack is: `bar` -> `foo`
    // so, our call-site is in `bar`
    console.log( “foo “ + this.a );
}
bar(); // ← call-site for `bar`
```

Here, this.a returns undefined, but if its call site is where `a` is declared, shouldn’t it have access to the variable `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` in `foo()` refers to the context in which it is called, in the snippet it is called in the global context which does not have the variable `a` defined in it so you get `undefined`.

Also you declared `a` using `let` which creates a block scoped variable. If you declared `a` outside the function using `var` it would have created a variable in the global scope.

In my snippet I created a object with two properties `a` and the `foo` method. Now if you call the `obj.foo()` method on the context of `obj` the `this` will point to the `obj` object and since I declared `a` using `var` in the global on invocation of `foo()` will print the value of `a` from the global scope:

```js
var a = "from global";

function bar() {
   //lexical context is global
   //let defines a variable in the enclosing scope
   let a = "heyo";
   console.log( "bar" );
   //foo is called within the global context, so this points to global object.
   foo(); 
   let obj = {a : "from obj", foo};
   // or foo.bind(obj); which sets the this context
   //now foo is called in the context of object "obj" so this points to obj
   obj.foo(); 
}
function foo() {
   console.log( "foo " + this.a );
}
bar();
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thank you very much. So using let means it can't be accessed by anything outside of its block scope correct?

Comment: @JoeSpinelli yes that is correct, its scope is limited to the enclosing block. Same is true for `const`.

Comment: but why wouldn't it work if let was declared in the global scope since this is referring to the global context and let is declared in the global scope?

Comment: @Joe Spinelli if you use var to declare a variable in the global scope then it gets added as a property of the global object. But doing the same using let or const doesn't make that a property of the global object. So if you did `let a = ...` that wouldn't have been accessible from `this.a` when `this` pointed to the global context.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, the question presented didn't contain `this` at all, which is interesting seeing as it is the one magical exception to the problem that was provided.

JavaScript is lexically scoped. That is, functions have access to the scope in which they are *defined*, not access to values which are at arbitrary positions of the current stack.

```js
const rememberX = (x) => () => x;
// a function that takes a value and returns a function
// when the inner function is called, it returns the value

let x = 5;
let x42 = rememberX(42);
let x10 = rememberX(10);
x = 20;

x42(); // 42
x10(); // 10
```

Lexical scoping provides the concept of closure, which is what makes the above work. Which makes it less like other languages in traditional circumstances, and more like a functional programming language.

Interestingly, `this` is the only value to break that mold. It is exceptionally late-bound, and determined at the moment of execution.

```js
class Person {
  constructor (name) {
    this.type = "person";
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayHi () {
    console.log(`${this.name}, the ${this.type}, says “Hi”.`);
  }
}


const bob = new Person("Bob");
bob.sayHi(); // "Bob, the person, says “Hi”."

const spot = {
  type: "dog",
  name: "Spot",
  sayHi: bob.sayHi
};

spot.sayHi(); // "Spot, the dog, says “Hi”."

bob.sayHi.apply({
  type: "ape",
  name: "Grape"
}); // "Grape, the ape, says “Hi”."
// apply is a method that all functions have,
// which sets `this` for this invocation


const bind = function (method, overriddenThis) {
  return function (...args) {
    return method.apply(overriddenThis, args);
  };
};
// bind also exists as a method on functions,
// to prevent `this` from being overwritten, using closure

const sayHi = bind(bob.sayHi, bob);
sayHi.apply(spot); // "Bob, the person, says “Hi”."
```

So there is the reason your stack-based calls don't work as expected, why `this` is different than you expect, and how to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation :)